# Spring Security OAuth 2 with form login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to configure my Spring boot application to use a form login, and to verify the credentials using an OAuth 2 authorization server (sending the credentials from the form login to the user authorization URL.

However, when I'm using the following `SecurityConfig` and I go to a resource, rather than using a form login it redirects to the authorization server, asking for my credentials (using basic authentication) and then redirects back to the application itself.

I'm using the following `SecurityConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfig extends OAuth2SsoConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .logout()
            .and()
            .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                        .csrf()
                        .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
                        .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .formLogin();
    }

    // CSRF repository + filter
}
```

I am providing the `formLogin()` to the `configure()` method, but this doesn't seem to work.

The following configuration is in my `application.yml` file:

```
spring:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: test
      clientSecret: secret
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8081/uaa/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8081/uaa/oauth/authorize
      clientAuthenticationScheme: header
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:8081/uaa/user
```

This configuration does work, because after the redirect I am getting authorized, but it's not in the way I would like it to work (with a form login in stead of a redirect to the OAuth2 Authorization server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SSO the whole point is that the user authenticates with the auth server (localhost:8081 in your case). If you want a form login, that's where you need to implement it, not in the client app.

Comment: There are legitimate reasons for providing both OAuth 2.0 and another form of authentication.

Comment: True. And it's fully supported by Spring Security. This question is old now and relates to old, unsupported versions of Spring projects. Anyone reading it should look at the Spring Security user guide for up to date information.