# Spring Boot login login returns 401 with matching credentials

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring Boot application which is able to login and register new users. My users are saved in a database (so far, I use in-memory H2 databse for testing).

The service is secured with OAuth2 (it is an auth server for other services I am developing).

Everything works fine and I am able to check the user's credentials but I would like to redirect the user somewhere after successful login. It works if I access the login page with the `response_type=token` parameter.

```
http://localhost:9000/auth/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=client&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9000/auth/user
```

But when I access the login page directly and login, it redirects me to the page I selected as my default success page but without the token or anything else that would indicate that the user is logged in and I get 401. Going straight to the `/login` and using the correct credentials results in this:

```
<oauth>
  <error_description>
    Full authentication is required to access this resource
  </error_description>
  <error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

Could someone point out to me what I need to adjust to make the login work?

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@Order(-20)
@EnableResourceServer
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // @formatter:off
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/register", "/confirm").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access", "/register", "/confirm")
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
        // @formatter:on

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

}
```

OAuth2Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    // password encryptor
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
        configurer.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        configurer.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        configurer.tokenStore(tokenStore);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

}
```

LoginController:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Login page:

```
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <form class="form-signin" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign in</h2>

            <div th:if="${param.error}">Invalid username and password.</div>
            <div th:if="${param.logout}">You have been logged out.</div>

            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email</label> 
            <input type="text" id="username"
                class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="username" th:required="required" th:autofocus="autofocus" />
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>

            <input type="password" id="inputPassword"
                class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" th:required="required" />

            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>

    </div>
    <!-- /container -->

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Thank you for any help. I am happy to provide more details if this is not enough.

EDIT: What I want is basically a steteless authentication between the Auth server and other microservices but sessions-based login on the Auth server itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check this first:
[Spring Security OAuth 2 with form login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33386883/spring-security-oauth-2-with-form-login)

Provided that an access token is being created with basic form login, I would add custom authentication success handler:

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Autowired
private AuthenticationSuccessHandler myAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

// 

.formLogin()
.loginPage("/login")
.defaultSuccessUrl("/")
.successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
```

And the handler "MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler":

```
@Component("myAuthenticationSuccessHandler")
public class MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    //logic to grant access
}
```

Comment: That is one possibility. But would it be also possible to have some kind of sessions? So the token would be used for external clients and session would be held on the auth server after the form login? All the other examples work out of the box so I am not sure what I am doing wrong in mine...

Comment: See if this helps:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785628/spring-security-oauth-2-0-client-secret-always-required-for-authorization-code

Comment: I don't think that this post is linked to my issue

Comment: Could you, please, provide an example how the success handler should look like? So the redrected url won't return 401.

Comment: Hey are you running two servers? Like the auth server is running on port 9000 and the resource server on port 8080 or something?